# How to change text transparency in the Mac preview?

Tags: macos, text, color, image-editing

[image]

This text is the watermark I want to add. Just wondering how to change its transparency.

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/watermark-pdf-pages-quick-actions-macos/ See this article that achieves the same thing and you might need to search for related automator questions.  the best I can suggest without much trouble is to use grey coloured text.

Answer (score 3):

https://maketecheasier.com/watermark-pdf-pages-quick-actions-macos  has a solution with automator to achieve the text transparency adjustment.

And I found another solution, using Keynote:

Load Image in Keynote, and text in Keynote can set transparency using View menu -> Show colours (CMD + Shift + C).

[image]